# Calculate which of the four fundamental subspaces a vector belongs to

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

[image]

Above you have the question (b) and it's answer underneath. I am out of the blue as how they proved that it belongs to the nullspace of $A^{T}$?

Comment: Is your question how they got it out of the blue or how the found it at all?

Comment: does not $q_3$ belong to the left null space of $A?$

Comment: @GitGud The process of solving it!

Comment: @abel Yes it does! I don't know how to calculate it!

Comment: @KarlMorrison, have you computed $q_1$ and $q_2?$

Comment: @abel Indeed I have! However rogerl just explained the answer, it was a type of trick question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what theorems you have access to: The column space of $A$ is orthogonal to left null space of $A$, which is the kernel of $A^T$. The column space is spanned by $q_1$ and $q_2$. Since $q_3$ is orthogonal to both $q_1$ and $q_2$, it is not in the span of $q_1$ and $q_2$, so it is in the left null space.

Comment: The claim that begins in your first line can't be true: $\;A\;$ is a $\;3\times2\;$ matrix and is thus defined in a two dimensional space, whereas its image is a three dimensional space.

Comment: @Timbuc Very true. I should never post before my coffee. Unfortunately, this answer is now accepted and I cannot delete it.

Comment: @rogerl Well then just rewrite your answer.  Say that the column space is orthogonal to the *left* nullspace and the direct sum of the two spaces is the *codomain* of the transformation.